# detect play status in phonegap media API

Tags: cordova, media-player

My recent project use phonegap 2.8.0 to build a music radio app. In the project, I use the media API to play a mp3 file from remote server a lot.When the net is bad, the media just pause(or stop, I can't figure it out) and some seconds(or minutes......) pasts it continue play. I just want when it pause(or stop) because of bad net condition , I can konw how many percent it has loaded, just like 10%,20%,30%.In the Phonegap document, I can't find anything to solve the problem.And I really hope someone could give me help.THX.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no such progress information given by the Media API. Maybe you could combine it with the FileTransfer.download() function, which gives you progress:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_onprogress